# Where can I download elementary OS Luna, now that Freya has been released?

Tags: system-installation, luna

Where may I download the *very latest **stable** version of elementary OS **Luna***?

---

Freya, unfortunately, is too unstable at this time. And while I write a wireless device driver for the ROG G20AJ Desktop PC, I'd prefer to be writing it in a more stable version of elementary OS.

But they've taken elementary OS Luna down from their site, and the one on SourceForge - well, I have no idea which one to pick. Does anyone have a direct, official link?

Comment: Just as a note, Luna will be unsupported from the release of 0.3.1, which is well on its way.

Comment: @LewisGoddard Sigh...

Comment: You should try the next release when it comes out, it's basically all bug-fixes and a kernel upgrade.

Comment: See http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/where-can-i-download-luna/7237#7237 now that the official downloads are gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems pretty direct and official to me: http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/stable/elementaryos-stable-amd64.20130810.iso/download ;)

Comment: Oh, lol. I did see that before, but when I read the date in the filename, I thought, "last one in 2013?" I thought there must have been newer ones around somewhere. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Elementary OS Luna is still  available here... https://old.elementary.io/

Comment: At the time of writing this question, I forgot to mention that link kept returning a 404.