# Where can I download Luna?

Tags: system-installation, luna

Where can I download Luna? All the files are gone from SourceForge.

(Yes, I know that Freya is out, I know that Luna is not supported anymore. I need a link to a Luna ISO.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, first of all, I would like to express how disappointed I am for having to spend more than an hour trying to download the previous release of what is currently one of the most popular distributions.

While the developers certainly have the right to decide what they are going to host, I believe it is a reasonable expectation of users who may have come to depend on your software that earlier versions will be available for download as long as the project is alive.

Furthermore, given that one can still find the ISO on different trackers, the checksum of which *does* *not* *match* [the official](https://old.elementary.io/answers/what-are-the-checksums-for-the-elementary-luna-isos), I’d say removing the downloads is even irresponsible.

---

For those who still wish to download Elementary OS Luna, someone has shared it [on Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9M1TKaD_dgIQWVWVzRqUUhLUkk/view). SHA256 checks out.

If that link goes down, contact me at adam@jooadam.hu, and I will make it available somewhere.

Comment: [This](http://blog.elementary.io/post/121768724076/goodbye-sourceforge) is the reason elementaryOS moved to DigitalOcean.

Comment: @PanagiotisTabakis That’s a valid reason to leave SourceForge. It’s not a valid a reason to not making previous releases available.

Comment: @ Joó Ádám Agree. Just wanted to clarify. You could accept your answer aswell.